# Token export error

Tags: truffle

I am writing tests for my smart contract and when I type in "truffle test" I keep getting this error. Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:231:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Mocha.loadFiles (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:228:14)
    at Mocha.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:536:10)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/test.js:125:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

Comment: Can you show us your test code?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fixed by adding the babel package:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/664

You can check truffle.js in this Truffle Box:

https://github.com/adrianmcli/truffle-react